# java : voice chat and text chat

Tags: java, chat, voice

I want to make a card game made in Java. People can run it on their pc. They can add their friends to their contacts list and when there are 4 players online they can begin a game by one of the players hosting the game. The players can communicate by text or by voice chat  Think of it like a chat client that allows users to play a card game and allows voice chat between the 4 players at the same time.

i dont know how do go abt the above project.Can anyone suggest me 
some framework or other things that i can use to devlop the above app?
Will it be like a p2p application?

Comment: If you are new to Java, I think you might be in over your head with this project. Start simple and build up. Worry about one thing at a time. For example, make a card game that only you can play.

Comment: i mean i an not  a exper in java.I have done many project in java using hibernate struts

Answer (score 1):

Start with chat using this [tutorial](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/10/05/instant-messaging-for-jabber-with-smack.html). Run your own jabber client or use gTalk and write some code for the client side.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you are going to make some kind of browser or desktop game app with both text and audio chat options.

For chat app you will need a backend and client-side solutions.

If I understand you right, you have not much experience with chat apps, so preparing everything from scratch might be tricky for you.

Therefore, I'd recommend trying a ready backend and SDK for developing chat and audio chat part of your app. That should spare a lot of effort and work for you and you will be able to concentrate on UI implementation of your chat and audio chat.

Since you need both text chat and audio chat solutions, I can recommend [ConnectyCube](https://connectycube.com/), since there you can find both at one place.
For browser or desktop apps you can use JS SDK. Here is the [documentation](https://developers.connectycube.com/js/) how to connect it to your project.